# Android emulator shows a black page while running the cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm developing an android app on `Cordova`. It just has one `index.html` page which includes 1300 lines.

I've built and run my last simple apps on emulator successfully, but when I'm trying to run this specific project, the emulator runs the app but just shows a black page.

[image]

I tried these commands:

```
cordova run android

cordova emulate android

ionic run android

ionic emulate android
```

And I get this lines on `cmd`

```
debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\Users\Administrator\siminsarmayeh\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-
debug.apk
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator 'emulator-5554'.
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: C:\Users\Administrator\siminsarmayeh\platforms\android\ant-build\Cord
ovaApp-debug.apk
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

But I get the same black page every time.

I'm using `API-19 (Android 4.4.2)` on emulator.

Is this because I'm testing a pretty big project?

**Edit**

This is my index `Head tag`

```
<head>

    <!-- ==============================================
        Title and basic Metas
        =============================================== -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>

    <!-- ==============================================
        Mobile Metas
        =============================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- ==============================================
        Favicons
        =============================================== -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/icon/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">

    <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css' href='css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome.min-css' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/modernizr.custom.97074.js'></script>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/quickmetro_map.js'></script>
    <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
    <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
    <link rel='prev' title='Blog' href='http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/blog/' />
    <link rel='next' title='Fullwidth Page' href='http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/fullwidth-page/' />
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.7.1" />
    <link rel='canonical' href='http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/' />
    <link rel='shortlink' href='http://theme-art.com/quickmetro-wp/?p=44' />
    <style type="text/css">
        .recentcomments a {
            display: inline !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: NASSIM,"Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
            font-size: 15px !important;
            background-color:#D0D8DD;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            font-family: "Quicksand", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 50px !important;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 34px !important;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 26px !important;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 28px !important;
        }

        h5 {
            font-size: 38px !important;
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 17px !important;
        }

        .navbar {
            font-family: "PT Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
            font-size: 25px !important;
            font-family: NASSIM;
        }

        .home-link {
            width: 134px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url(images/icon/logo.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .section.home {
            background-image: url(uploads/2013/11/home-bg.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .section.portfolio {
        }

        .section.about {
        }

        .section.service {
        }

        .section.team {
        }

        .section.client {
        }

        .section.contact {
        }

        .tile-portfolio {
            background: #00c6ff;
        }

        .tile-about {
            background: #f39c12;
        }

        .tile-service {
            background: #FD2561;
        }

        .tile-team {
            background: #FF08FF;
        }

        .tile-client {
            background: #49E035;
        }

        .tile-contact {
            background: #1B3146;
        }

        .modal-content {
            background: #005286;
        }

        .contact-box {
            background: #1A6593;
            background: rgba(26, 101, 147,0.9);
        }

        .tweet-box {
            background: #5398AF;
        }

        .skills {
            background: #146FA8;
            background: rgba(20,111,168,0.9);
        }

        .about-box {
            background: #146FA8;
            background:  rgba(20,111,168,0.9);
        }

        .check-our-work a {
            background: #4FBAFF;
            background: rgba(79,186,255,0.9);
        }

        .feature-box {
            background: #3196D6;
            background:rgba(49, 150, 214,0.9);
        }

        .team-member {
            background:#3196D6;
            background: rgba(49, 150, 214,0.9);
        }

        .navbar {
            background: #1A6593 !important;

        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }

        .client .quotes {
            background: #2D92FF;
            background: rgba(45,146,255,0.8);
        }

            .client .quotes:after {
                border-left-color: #2D92FF;
                border-left-color: rgba(45,146,255,0.8);
            }

        .client .photos .author {
            background: #2D92FF;
            background: rgba(45,146,255,0.8);
        }

        @media (max-width:767px) {
            .client .quotes:after {
                border-left-color: transparent;
            }

            .client .quotes:before {
                border-bottom-color: #2D92FF;
                border-bottom-color: rgba(45,146,255,0.8);
            }
        }
        #qrpopup
        {
        position:fixed;z-index:9999;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.9);width:100%; height:100%;display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: can you show the head tag of index.html file?

Comment: @frank I added my head tag in edit

Comment: u have not included `cordova.js` file in the index.html? check whether you can see `cordova.js` in the `platforms\android\assets\www` directory. You need to include the `cordova.js` file. e.g `<script type='text/javascript' src='cordova.js'></script>`

Comment: @frank Good point! That was the problem! You should've put it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included `cordova.js` file in your `index.html`. Add this line to it:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='cordova.js'></script>
```